# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf Form Error => i want edit line selected from table

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to edit a row of a table in another html page.
I have a beginner with thymeleaf and Spring MVC...

profilesAll.html

[image]

but, i have this error :
*org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputRadioFieldTagProcessor' (template: "profilsAll" - line 39, col 26)*
....

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'profil' available as request attribute*

**ProfilsAll.html** :

```
<form th:action="@{/profiles/update}" th:object="${profil}" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>Select</th> 
                <th>UID</th>
                <th>SIP</th>
                <th>enterpriseVoiceEnabled</th>
                <th>voicePolicy</th>
                <th>dialPlan</th>
                <th>samAccountName</th>
                <th>exUmEnabled</th>
                <th>exchUser</th>
                <th>objectClass</th>
                <th>statusProfile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:if="${skypeProfiles.empty}">
                <td colspan="2"> No skype profile available </td>
            <tr th:each="skypeProfile, profile:${skypeProfiles}">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" th:field="*{profile}" th:value="${profile}" />
                </td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.collaboraterId}>UID</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.SIP}>SIP</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.enterpriseVoiceEnabled}>enterpriseVoiceEnabled</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.voicePolicy}>voicePolicy</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.dialPlan}>dialPlan</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.samAccountName}>samAccountName</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.exUmEnabled}>exUmEnabled</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.exchUser}>exchUser</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.objectClass}>objectClass</td>
                <td th:text=${skypeProfile.statusProfile}>statusProfile</td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" value ="Edit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller :**

```
@PostMapping("profiles/update")
public String profilesUpdate(@ModelAttribute("profil") SkypeProfileSearchBean skypeProfile) {
    
    System.out.print("skypeProfile id "+skypeProfile.getCollaboraterId());
    return "profilsUpdate";
}
```

This code is problematic but I did not find the solution :

```
<input type="radio" th:field="*{profile}" th:value="${profile}" />
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Where does your if condition end in the template ??
`<tr th:if="${skypeProfiles.empty}">
<td colspan="2"> No skype profile available </td>`

Comment: Yes, i forgot the closing tag </tr>.
I deleted this test but still have the same problem.

Comment: replace `<tr th:each="skypeProfile, profile:${skypeProfiles}">`
with  `<tr th:each="skypeProfile : ${skypeProfiles}">`

and  `<input type="radio" th:field="*{profile}" th:value="${profile}" />`
with  `<input type="radio" th:field="*{skypeProfile}" th:value="${skypeProfile}" />`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two instances of skypeProfiles to use one in object and display one. Just having one instance would be enough.
Ref - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

replace `<tr th:each="skypeProfile, profile:${skypeProfiles}">`
with  `<tr th:each="skypeProfile : ${skypeProfiles}">`

and  `<input type="radio" th:field="*{profile}" th:value="${profile}" />`
with  `<input type="radio" th:field="*{skypeProfile}" th:value="${skypeProfile}" />`

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your answer but i have the same error...

Comment: First is your table getting printed ? Show your get mapping - it should first have all values for the profile.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951501/how-to-use-input-radio-button-with-thymeleaf-and-spring-mvc

Comment: Also could be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743806/error-during-execution-of-processor-org-thymeleaf-spring5-processor-springinput